# Circle above a letter

Tags: symbols

I could write a circle above the letter but it seems far a little bit

[image]

Is there a way to get it down a little bit, because I really use it a lot and it takes a lot of space.
Here is a sample of the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{yourStyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\MakeUppercase\currentname}
 }

\begin{document}

 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\right)^\mathsf{c} =  (\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}^{\circ})_{\tau_1}$$
 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_2}\right)^\mathsf{c} = (\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}^{\circ})_{\tau_2}$$
```

Comment: What maths or physics notation is this? What does it mean?

Comment: @smci I do not know about physics this is related to mathematics, and it means the interior of a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps with the use of stacks.  The current `\circ` elevation is controlled by the `-2pt` optional argument to `\stackon`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\right)^\mathsf{c} =  
  (\stackon[-2pt]{\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}}{\scriptstyle\circ})_{\tau_1}\]
\[\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_2}\right)^\mathsf{c} = 
  (\stackon[-2pt]{\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}}{\scriptstyle\circ})_{\tau_2}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even make it a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\bracecirc[1]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{-2pt}
  {\aoverbrace[L1R]{#1}}{\scriptstyle\circ}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\right)^\mathsf{c} =  
  (\bracecirc{M^\mathsf{c}})_{\tau_1}\]
\[\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_2}\right)^\mathsf{c} = 
  (\bracecirc{M^\mathsf{c}})_{\tau_2}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much

Comment: @TarekAcila You are welcome.  I edited the macro form definition, to make it impervious to changes in `stackengine` defaults elsewhere in the document.  That is, you can change defaults for `stackengine` if your document has different uses for it, without breaking this macro definition.

Answer (score 5):

I have changed the initial code completely: there are the combination of two particular packages: *accents* and *scalerel*. With these packages I have created a macro called `\arcsup` with the arc only above the character . If you want to have a large horizontal arc you can increase the value of `\hstretch{1.8}` to stretch horizzontally the arc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\arcsup[1]{\accentset{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\circ}{\hstretch{1.8}{\frown}}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[\bigl((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\bigr)^{\!\mathsf{c}} =  (\arcsup{M}^\mathsf{c})_{\tau_1}\]
 \end{document}
```

You can see the increment to

```
\hstretch{2.5}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** If you prefer, a smaller `\circ` symbol you can use the option,

```
\scaleto{\circ}{2pt}%%%% <----- 2pt, or any value neq 0
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand\arcsup[1]{\accentset{\overset{\scaleto{\circ}{2pt}}{\hstretch{1.8}{\frown}}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[\bigl((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\bigr)^{\!\mathsf{c}} =  (\arcsup{M}^\mathsf{c})_{\tau_1}\]
 \end{document}
```

these are the screeshots for comparison:

[image]

```
\scaleto{\circ}{1.5pt}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but the package [yhmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/yhmath) have the `\widering` command which can be useful to you:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{yourStyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\MakeUppercase\currentname}
 }

\begin{document}

 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\right)^\mathsf{c} =  (\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}^{\circ})_{\tau_1}$$
 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_2}\right)^\mathsf{c} = (\aoverbrace[L1R] 
 {M^\mathsf{c}}^{\circ})_{\tau_2}$$

 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\right)^\mathsf{c} =  (\widering{M^\mathsf{c}})_{\tau_1}$$
 $$\left((\overline{M})_{\tau_2}\right)^\mathsf{c} = (\widering{M^\mathsf{c}})_{\tau_2}$$

\end{document}
```

[image: yhmath widering]

Answer (score 1):

In the recent version 1.18 of [`newtxmath`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf) there are new math accents and macros. The macro `\widering`, as written into the guide, places a ring centered over an `\overgroup`,
not dissimilar from its use in `yhmath`. But for my tastes the command `\widering` given by `newtxmath` have a better arc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}

\begin{document}
\[\bigl((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\bigr)^{\!\mathsf{c}} =  (\widering{M}{}^{\mathsf{c}})_{\tau_1}\]
\end{document}
```

See this output:

[image]

Or changed the position of superscript:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}

\begin{document}
\[\bigl((\overline{M})_{\tau_1}\bigr)^{\!\mathsf{c}} =  (\widering{M^{\mathsf{c}}})_{\tau_1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]